Issues with Android 14/EAP-TLS
Pursuant to this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-enterprise
If a company is using a RADIUS certificate that is using a generic DNS name for the RADIUS server in the DNS SAN e.g. "server"
Is it even possible for EAP-TLS to work?
